# Would the error log for MySQL for the IBM i be in mysql.general_log?

Tags: mysql, iseries

I have an IBM i running Zend DBI (Zend Supported MySQL 5.1) that I'm trying to find log information for. I do `SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log` and get 0 rows.

my.cnf looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=100M
innodb_log_file_size=20M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
key_buffer_size=64M
table_cache=256
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size=1M
bulk_insert_buffer_size=8M
```

Process startup looks like this:

> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql/bin/my.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysqldata --port=3306 --user=mysql --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --pid-file=/usr/local/mysqldata/zmysql.pid --tmpdir=/tmp

Am I looking in the wrong place for error messages

Comment: Error log is `mysqld.err`.  It cannot be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

According to `SHOW VARIABLES` general_log is OFF and log_error is blank. So the default configuration is to not log anything.

Comment: are you sure it's not in `/usr/local/mysqldata` as _hostname_.err ?